# Difference between Long.valueOf(java.lang.String) and new Long(java.lang.String)?

Tags: java, coding-style, long-integer

I'm consolidating code written by two different people and notice that casting a String value into a Long has been done in two different ways.

Coder #1 has done this:

```
String strId = "12345678";
...
Long lId = new Long(strId);
```

While coder #2 has done this:

```
String strId = "12345678";
...
Long lId = Long.valueOf(strId);
```

Functionally, the code operates exactly the same.  There's a try/catch block around each bit to handle any `NumberFormatException` that is thrown.  The incoming string value is an 8 digit string that represents a decimal: `"12345678"` and in both cases it is correctly converted into `Long`.

Is there any functional difference between passing the string in the constructor and using Long.valueOf()?  I've checked the constructor doc here:

[Long(java.lang.String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#Long%28java.lang.String%29)

and the docs for valueOf() here:

[Long.valueOf(java.lang.String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29)

As far as I can tell, they  both call parseLong() so it doesn't matter which is used.  I just want to make sure I'm not setting myself up for some strange behavior further down the road.  Also, is either style more "correct" (haha) than the other?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**The difference is that** using `new Long()` you will always create a new object, while using `Long.valueOf()`, may return you the cached value of `long` if the value is between `[-128 to 127]`.

So, you should prefer `Long.valueOf` method, because it may save you some memory.

If you see the source code for `Long.valueOf(String)`, it internally invokes `Long.valueOf(long)`, whose source code I have posted below: -

```
public static Long valueOf(String s) throws NumberFormatException
{
    return Long.valueOf(parseLong(s, 10));
}

public static Long valueOf(long l) {
    final int offset = 128;
    if (l >= -128 && l <= 127) { // will cache 
        return LongCache.cache[(int)l + offset];
    }
    return new Long(l);
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I understood before looking up this http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Long.java Could you please share the source link.

Comment: @ArunManivannan.. You can find the source code in the jdk installation directory. Go to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk` there will be an `src` folder. Might be in zipped format. Unzip it. Go to `java -> lang -> Long.class` to see the source code.

Comment: This is very helpful, thanks for the code snippet and the explanation.

Comment: @torgis. You're welcome :). Whenever you have doubt on some method. Remember, you always have the source code to check. In your `JDK` Installation directory. You just need to know the appropriate package name to search in.

Comment: It may save memory but usually it will waste processor time

Answer (score 8):

`Long.valueOf()` should be preferred: it returns cached values of Long for some often-used values instead of constructing a new instance as the constructor does.

Even if some Java versions don't use a cache, using `valueOf()` makes it possible in future versions, whereas the constructor will always create a new instance.

Comment: That value range is `[-128 to 127]` to be specific. But, I think that can be changed. Don't know how exactly.

Answer (score 3):

They mean the same

```
public static Long valueOf(String s) throws NumberFormatException{
        return new Long(parseLong(s, 10));
}

public Long(String s) throws NumberFormatException {
    this.value = parseLong(s, 10);
}
```

[Source JDK 6.0](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Long.java)

Comment: Arun, they are same if the s is out of some range(-128 t0 127), if s in with-in range, they are not same.

Comment: Which version of Java are you using? In my Java 6 and 7 versions, a cache is used.

Comment: @Nambari I thought so too. However, the implementation is surprising.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks for the note. 6.0. Edited the post accordingly.

Comment: You first method does not return `new Long(parseLong(s, 10));` rather `Long.valueOf(parseLong(s, 10));`. See my post.

Comment: Even in JDK 6 they don't **literally** mean the same; they just happen to have the same behavior. Their **meaning** is defined by the Javadoc.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Ouch. That was painful. Cutting off **literally** from the answer

Comment: The point is not in the "literally", but in the fact that, at least in Java, implementation code is not the specification, so you cannot make arguments about the meaning of methods by demonstrating their implementation. If this were Ruby, on the other hand, you'd be much more entitled to it.

Answer (score 3):

Both do `parseLong(String, int)` internally (int being radix with value as 10), but `valueOf` has advantage as documented below:

`If a new Long instance is not required, this method should generally be used in preference to the constructor Long(long), as this method is likely to yield significantly better space and time performance by caching frequently requested values.`

Answer (score 0):

This is the PMD plugin out put which is run on eclipse

Code I checked is

```
Long l = new Long("123456");
```

In JDK 1.5, calling new Long() causes memory allocation. Long.valueOf() is more memory friendly.

Answer (score 0):

i am thinking how to change range and size of the cache for our application, overloaded with Longs;

such change is not supported by j2se api
One way is to change loaded java byte code with ClassLoader or even with JVMTI
(it allows to keep such trick out of the project, like external tuning)

or, may be, to create external cache and own static cachedValueOf()
which is straight forward, but the code depending on some not applicational needs is not nice

Comment: Is it answer for question? You should use `question` option for ask questions.