# How to return 2D long array with JNI

Tags: java-native-interface, return-value, multidimensional-array

I'm writing a code which must return a long array from C to java using JNI. But the method (*env)->FindClass returns NULL whatever I tried.

Here is my code :

```
// Returns a 2D long array from C to Java
JNIEXPORT jobjectArray JNICALL Java_awax_tools_AcquisitionWrapper_startAcquisition (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {

    // (...) Acquisition code

    // The 2D long array to return
    long** primitive2DArray = data;

    // Get the long array class
    jclass longArrayClass = (*env)->FindClass(env, "[java/lang/Long");

    // Check if we properly got the long array class
    if (longArrayClass == NULL) {
        // Ooops
        return NULL;
    }

    // Create the returnable 2D array
    jobjectArray myReturnable2DArray = (*env)->NewObjectArray(env, (jsize) length1D, longArrayClass, NULL);

    // Go through the firs dimension and add the second dimension arrays
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < length1D; i++) {
        jlongArray longArray = (*env)->NewLongArray(env, length2D);
        (*env)->SetLongArrayRegion(env, longArray, (jsize) 0, (jsize) length2D, (jlong*) primitive2DArray[i]);
        (*env)->SetObjectArrayElement(env, myReturnable2DArray, (jsize) i, longArray);
        (*env)->DeleteLocalRef(env, longArray);
    }

    // Return a Java consumable 2D long array
    return myReturnable2DArray;
}
```

I also tried with :

```
(*env)->FindClass(env, "[L")
(*env)->FindClass(env, "[Long")
(*env)->FindClass(env, "[java.lang.Long")
```

But none of them seems to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really want an array of `java.lang.Long` objects, you have to write `[Ljava/lang/Long;`. If you create an array of those, you get `[[Ljava/lang/Long;` which would be `Long[][]` on the Java side.

However, this is *terribly inefficient*. You have to create an object for **every single number** inside that array. Using `Long.valueOf` [can give you cached objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13145360/1590632) but I doubt that many values inside that array fit into a signed byte.

Instead of `Long` objects, you should use primitive `long` values. Everything except the first line of your code is already doing that. The correct internal name for an array of primitive `long`s is `[J`:

```
jclass longArrayClass = (*env)->FindClass(env, "[J");
```

The rest of your code is correct and the method will return a `long[][]`.

---

But watch out: You aren't saying anything about which platform you're using, but on Windows for example, this still won't work: A `long` there is just an `int` in disguise, it's also a 32 bit value. A `jlong` on the other hand always has 64 bits and is typedef'd to a `long long`  for exactly that reason. You're blindly casting the pointers, so your code would try to copy twice as much data as you actually have.

Comment: I didn't precise but yes I want the primitive type. I tried and it works fine with "[J" thank you. For the platform it will be both linux and windows, but what I need is just to be able to return values on 3 bytes minimum, so what is the best way to do that ?

Comment: You could iterate over the second dimension instead of using the SetRegion function and cast the values entry by entry. That should work.

Answer (score 1):

`[java/lang/Long` should be written as `[Ljava/lang/Long;` and refers to a type, not a class.

The class is `Ljava/lang/Long;`, which consistent with what [`NewObjectArray`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#wp21619) requires—the class for the elements:

```
jobjectArray NewObjectArray(JNIEnv *env, jsize length,
jclass elementClass, jobject initialElement);
```

BTW—Java does support primitive `long` arrays, which might be faster or simplier if you can change your native method return type.

Comment: Yes what I want is the primitive type, but why do I have to change the return type ?

Comment: Because `jlongArray` (`long[]`) is not the same as `jobjectArray` (`Long[]`). You can create a `jlongArray` with going through `FindClass`. See [NewLongArray](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#wp17318).

Comment: Sorry, I was thrown off by your use of "long array". You want return a C 2-D array of long. Java actually doesn't have multi-dimensional arrays. You have to return an array of arrays. The "inner" arrays can be `long[]`; the result is an object array. See @main--'s answer.