# Difference between Long.getLong(s), Long.valueOf(s), Long.parseLong(s) where "s" is a String Type

Tags: java, difference

I want to convert a String to Long. But I have found 4 different ways to archive that propouse.

> Long.getLong(s) - Determines the long value of the system property
>   with the specified name.
>
> Long.valueOf(s) - Returns a Long object holding the value of the
>   specified String
>
> Long.parseLong(s) - Parses the string argument as a signed decimal
>   long.
>
> new Long(s) - Constructs a newly allocated Long object that represents
>   the long value indicated by the String parameter

Besides that "parseLong()" return a long value and the other 3 return Long object.
What are the differences between them, what is the best case of use for them?(when to use them), which one gives better performance?

Thanks in advance.

---

### EDIT :

[This gave me the difference between "valueOf(s)" and "new Long(s)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13145267/difference-between-long-valueofjava-lang-string-and-new-longjava-lang-string) and 
also found [the diference between "valueOf(s)" and "Long.parseLong(s)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/508665/difference-between-parseint-and-valueof-in-java).

But I still dont get Long.getLong(s) what is used for. What does "Determines the long value of the system property with the specified name" means?

---

Comment: The javadoc for [`Long.valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#valueOf(long)) explains "...this method should generally be used in preference to the constructor ..."

Comment: If you look at the source code, `Long.parseLong` is basically used by all the other methods.

Comment: `Long.getLong()` is completely different, it's used to read system properties, not to convert the input string to a long. Performance is irrelevant.

Comment: The constructor is deprecated. You should use `parseLong(...)` instead. `Long.getLong(...)` determines the `Long`-value of a System property.

Comment: If you don't know what something does, your first stop should be the Javadoc. [`Long.getLong()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#getLong-java.lang.String-) is - in my opinion - pretty well documented.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Long.getLong(s)` does not convert the string inside to long ("123" does not become 123). The string inside is a certain name that the native library will return a long value accordingly.

`Long.valueOf(s)` when s is string is similar to this one: `new Long(Long.parseLong(s))`

`Long.valueOf(l)` when l is a `long` type will convert the primary data type long to Long. Read about Unboxing and Autoboxing in java

`Long.parseLong(s)` will convert the string inside to long value.

So they are all different except for `Long.valueOf(l)` and `Long.parseLong(s)` they are almost the same however the first one returns a `Long` object and the other one returns a `long` the primary data type.

Comment: I know what `Long.getLong` does, but I have no idea what you mean with _"The string inside is a certain name that the native library will return a long value accordingly."_ `Long.getLong` has nothing to with native libraries. It gets the value of the system property with the name passed to `getLong` and converts that value to a `Long` (or `null` if not convertible). See also the javadoc of [`Long.getLong()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#getLong-java.lang.String-) (which explains it pretty well).

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel The person who asked the question thinks that the 4 statements are the same. I did not provide an entire explanation of what `Long.getLong` does, I only provided the explanation that it does not convert the `String` to `Long` ( It doesn't `parse` it ). The question is not about what each one does, the question is about which one should he uses and which is more optimized.

Comment: You didn't address the part that I have no clue what you mean with _"The string inside is a certain name that the native library will return a long value accordingly."_. That is not what it does, as far as I can make sense of it.